# above average query in microsoft access - Design view

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

The table contains 2 columns - the first type is `AutoNumber(ID)`, and the second is `Number(Value)`.

I need to show the ID's of those who their Value is above the average.

How can I do that in the Design view(not with sql, only at the Design view)?

I'm facing following error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaDK9.jpg)

Comment: please show your code ([mcve])

Comment: i know that i can use SQL, but i want to know if there an option to do that in the Design view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL like this:

```
SELECT id
FROM Table1
    ,(
        SELECT Avg(Table1.num) AS avgnum
        FROM Table1
        ) AS a
WHERE num > a.avgnum;
```

In design view you can do the same if you create an additional query with average calculation, let's call it qryAvg:

```
SELECT Avg(Table1.num) AS AvgOfnum
FROM Table1;
```

Then create another final query, which uses qryAvg:

```
SELECT Table1.id
FROM Table1, qryAvg
WHERE (((Table1.num)>[AvgOfNum]));
```

Unfortunately the query builder doesn't allow to work with subqueries in graphic mode, but in such kind simple cases you can avoid using subqueries at all, just use domain aggregate functions instead:

```
SELECT Table1.id
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.num)>DAvg("num","Table1")));
```

In this case if num is Long Integer, then you need to cast results of domain function to Long Integer:

```
SELECT Table1.id
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.num)>CLng(DAvg("num","Table1"))));
```

Comment: i know that i can use SQL, but i want to know if there an option to do that in the Design view